# Boundary to binary image - Matlab

Tags: matlab

In this code I extract the outline of an object. Is there a way to convert it to a fill holes binary image?

Code:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
 
url='https://vemaps.com/uploads/img/it-07.png';
I = imread(url);
imshow(I);
hold on;

BW = imbinarize(I);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');

k=1;
stat = regionprops(I,'Centroid');
b = B{k};
c = stat(k).Centroid;
yBoundary = b(:,2);
xBoundary = b(:,1);
cy = c(:,2);
cx = c(:,1);

plot(yBoundary, xBoundary, 'g', 'linewidth', 2);
```

This is the image outcome I look for:
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a sample image and the desired result. It's possible you're simply looking for the `L` matrix returned by `bwboundaries`.

Comment: Added an image. As the L is of all the image not of specific object, is it possible to get it for an object?

Comment: We need your original image to run your code and see where it's going wrong. All of the objects in `L` are labeled. Just pick which label you want to see, say `k`, and `L==k` will be your binary image.

Comment: The original image is found in https://vemaps.com/uploads/img/it-07.png

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the url was in the code. Here's the result I get from `L==19` with your input image. Note that your image may be labeled differently. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCuRB.png

Comment: Was that what you were looking for, or did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks, when I do imshow(L==1) I get the same object like in your link. Any reason why? How can I save the L==1 into a new binary object/image?

Comment: 1) As I said, your labeling might be different. Check the other labels and see which objects they correspond to. 2) Assign it to a variable? `out_img = (L==1)`?